# Files missing in Gitlab after push

Tags: git, gitlab

I recently pushed 4 commits to Gitlab, but now some of my files are missing. Whenever I attempt to view the files, I get an error like this:

`Not Found: /gitlab/root/my-app/blob/9f2cc9da2ee7e6b8d0e7506ce8fc89213b73a442/app/controllers/arrivals_controller.rb`

This applies for any commit, and the master branch. I've attempted to restart Gitlab, and clear the Resque cache as well but to no avail. I can pull the documents with a `git clone` command to a new directory.

Edit: Ran the test `bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` and here is the output

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.1 ? ... OK (1.7.1)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... 
Joshua Smock / INTO Arrivals Form ... ok

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... 
Joshua Smock / INTO Arrivals Form ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
Joshua Smock / INTO Arrivals Form ... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.1)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Everything seems okay on this end.

Comment: You still have these commits in your local repo. Try to push them one more time.

Comment: When I `git push origin master` it says `Everything up-to-date`

Comment: Try to delete and re-create your branch on the server?

Comment: That is a possibility but I'd rather just keep the current branch as is and recover the files that are somehow lost in Gitlab. The files do exist when I pull them down to download...

Comment: try running this command `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` to verify if everything is alright

Comment: I added the result of the test above @Eternal-Learner

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `gitlab-satellites` folder is corrupt. Delete that folder and recreate it. This folder is used by `gitlab` as a scratchpad - for merging etc. Deleting this folder should be mostly harmless. To be safer you can rename it to something else (instead of deleting) before running the following command.

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

and then restart `gitlab`.

Comment: I ran that but it's still giving me the error unfortunately. I assume that means that my git repository is corrupted?

Comment: don't think so, since you are able to `push` and `clone` successfully and have all your commits in the cloned repo. This is a sync issue between your `git` repos and the `gitlab` front end. Check if `sidekiq` is showing any errors.

Comment: I checked `sidekiq` and it didn't have any errors, but the server has restarted since this happened so it's not showing anything processed as of yet. Is there a log I can check?

Comment: Restarting server should not matter as `sidekiq` queues are persistent. Are all the queues empty? are there any jobs waiting for `retry`? Try pushing a new commit and watch if `sidekiq` picks it up. If `sidekiq` remains inactive... that is your problem.

Comment: All of the queues are empty, and none are waiting to retry. I changed my `Gemfile` and pushed it, and `sidekiq` picked it up and processed it.

Comment: Can you view the changed `Gemfile`? or you get the same error? If you still get the error, raise a ticket with gitlab team. In the meanwhile, you can try reinstalling `gitlab` on a clean slate. I am out of ideas. sorry.